# how to pass price variable to PayPal with encrypted button

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

The form contain the encrypted Paypal button.i want to pass the value/price variable to paypal.i dont kbow how to do that .

```
       <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
       <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
      <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="LMFWRYRBURU2J">

       <input  type="hidden"><h3>Amount of messages </h3> <br /> </div>
    <input class="paypal_input" type="" name="message" id="message" onkeyup="doMath()" maxlength="60"> <br /> 


      </p>
      <div  class="paypal_list2">   
          <p>
     <input type="hidden"><h3>Total amount</h3><br /> </div>
     <input id="total" class="paypal_input_1" type="text" value="" name="amount" readonly>

      <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
     <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
       </form>
```

i want to pass this variable  amount to the paypal with the encrypted button

i tried like this

```
       <input type='hidden' name='amount' value='<?php echo $_POST['total'];?>'>
```

it not taking amount .the item_price blank in the paypal .can anyone help me to how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

1. The only things that you can pass between websites are string values.
2. The other web site has to give you the names of the values that they will accept.
3. but this will passes values to Paypal.

   1. Add each hidden variable needed as follows 
      < input type=`hidden` id=`OrderID` value=`12345`>
   2. The button that will submit values to the external site 
      < input type="button" onclick="javascript: submitToPayPal(‘http://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr’);" value="Submit to PayPal" >
   3. Add the necessary JavaScript to the pages

```
   
    

    function submitToPayPal(formAction){ 
        var formElementsArray = document.getElementsByTagName('FORM’);
        if ( formElementsArray != null )  {   
            var formElement = formElementsArray[0];
            document.getElementById('total_amount’).value = '';         
            document.getElementById('__VIEWSTATE’).name = 'NOVIEWSTATE';
            formElement.action = formAction;
            formElement.submit();
        }
    }
```

Use the below if you good in php script.

```
    /*The item name and amount can be brought in dynamically by querying the $_POST['item_number'] variable.*/
    $querystring .= "item_name=".urlencode($item_name)."&";
    $querystring .= "amount=".urlencode($item_amount)."&";
```

```
/*loop for posted values and append to querystring*/
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$querystring .= "$key=$value&";
}

/* Append paypal return addresses*/
$querystring .= "return=".urlencode(stripslashes($return_url))."&";
$querystring .= "cancel_return=".urlencode(stripslashes($cancel_url))."&";
$querystring .= "notify_url=".urlencode($notify_url);

/* Append querystring with custom field
//$querystring .= "&custom=".USERID; */

/* Redirect to paypal IPN*/
header("location:https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr".$querystring);
exit();
```

.

Comment: without submitting the details directly from form post, you can form a string and pass it via header. Please check the php script what i have added.